# Laravel cronjob in server won't run

Tags: php, laravel, centos7, cyber-panel

I have my laravel app installed on subdomain of my website and I've set cronjob but it does not fire.

I've tested my command by terminal and its firing just fine so the issue is all about cronjob and not my command/console I guess.

#### Code

`Does not work`

```
1- /home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

2- php /home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

`kernel.php`

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\RenewInvoices::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
  $schedule->command('renew:invoices')
  ->everyMinute();
}
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved

Apparently I had to get my php from other place `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/php` rather than `/usr/bin/php`

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/php /home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com && /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/php /home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

To simplify command above and make it easy to read here is it's structure:

`PHP` `LARAVEL_APP` `&&` `PHP` `ARTISAN COMMAND` `>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

Cronjobs ignore PATH when it is run, so it may not work if the PATH information is not fully available to it.

Please try amending the cronjob so that the full path is used

For example, change "php" to "/usr/bin/php" (pls use your actual path of php in your server)

```
 /home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com && /usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

/usr/bin/php /home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com && /usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Please also include the full path of artisan. Thanks

Comment: still not running

Comment: Please also use the full path of artisan , for example /home/laravel-proj/artisan (artisan is in your Laravel project root)

Comment: I've tried this `/home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com && /usr/bin/php /home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` and this 
`/usr/bin/php /home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com && /usr/bin/php /home/example.com/public_html/process.example.com/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` both didn't work

Comment: If you run the modified , long version such as the command above when you are in TERMINAL, does it work ? (let's just check whether the paths are correct)